# merging and calculating sum in dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

```
let_col= {'t': ['black', 'golden', 'silver'], 'f': ['blue', 'green'], 's': ['grey', 'yellow'], 'k': ['red', 'purple']}

col_pix = {'blue':150,'red':200,'green':160,'grey':240,'purple':210,'black':140,'yellow':120,'golden':130,'silver':200}
```

I would  like to merge these two dictionaries as :

```
let_col_pixels = {'t': ['black':140, 'golden':130, 'silver':200],'f':[] ....}
```

Then I have to add total pixels for each letter. can someone please help me , I tried many things but still unable to do it. Thanks

Comment: Hi there, can you give examples of code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question right, this script will merge the dictionaries and adds key `total_sum` to each letter:

```
let_col= {'t': ['black', 'golden', 'silver'], 'f': ['blue', 'green'], 's': ['grey', 'yellow'], 'k': ['red', 'purple']}
col_pix = {'blue':150,'red':200,'green':160,'grey':240,'purple':210,'black':140,'yellow':120,'golden':130,'silver':200}

out = {k: dict(**v, total_sum=sum(v.values())) for k, v in {k:{vv: col_pix[vv] for vv in v}  for k, v in let_col.items()}.items()}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'f': {'blue': 150, 'green': 160, 'total_sum': 310},
 'k': {'purple': 210, 'red': 200, 'total_sum': 410},
 's': {'grey': 240, 'total_sum': 360, 'yellow': 120},
 't': {'black': 140, 'golden': 130, 'silver': 200, 'total_sum': 470}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First I have to create a dictionary like this :                                     {'f': {'blue': 150, 'green': 160},
 'k': {'purple': 210, 'red': 200},
 's': {'grey': 240, 'yellow': 120},
 't': {'black': 140, 'golden': 130, 'silver': 200}}           Then I have to create anthor dictionary with :            let_pix = {'f':total pix'} to answer questions like 'which letter has the most pixels'?